# std::vector<>型のiteratorを使いそのクラスのメンバ関数を使う方法が知りたい。

Tags: c++

for文２つですがどうやって`itr->mPlay();`などといった形で`class test`のメンバ関数`mPlay()`を参照出来るのか知りたいです。

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include "glm/ext.hpp"
#include <vector>

class test
{
    public:
        test(bool f) {
            frag = f;
        }

        bool mPlay()
        {
            printf("ああ\n");
            return frag;
        }

    private:
        bool frag;
};

std::vector<test*> v2;
std::vector<test>* v3 = new std::vector<test>;

int main()
{

    v3->push_back(test(false));
    v3->push_back(test(true));
    v3->push_back(test(false));

    printf("v3\n\n");

    for (std::vector<test>::iterator itr = v3->begin(); itr != v3->end(); itr++)
    {
        //itr->mPlay();     
    }

    printf("\n\n v2\n\n");

    v2.push_back(new test(false));
    v2.push_back(new test(true));
    v2.push_back(new test(false));

    for (std::vector<test*>::iterator itr = v2.begin(); itr != v2.end(); itr++)
    {
        //itr->mPlay();     
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `v2` に対しては `std::vector<test*>::iterator itr = ...` としています(reference)ので dereference する必要がありますね。

Comment: どいう意味でしょうか？詳細にお願い出来ますでしょうか？

Comment: コンパイラのエラーメッセージはコンパイルの問題を解決するのにとても重要なので、エラーメッセージも質問に含めてください。

Comment: @Matsuzawa 詳細という程でもなく、`(*itr)->mPlay();` とする必要がありますよ、という事です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`v3` は `itr` が「`test` を指すポインタのようなもの」なので、`itr->mPlay()` でコンパイルできるはずです。

`v2` は `itr` が「`test*` を指すポインタのようなもの」なので、デリファレンスして `(*itr)->mPlay()` または `(**itr).mPlay()`となります。

現在の C++ ではこういった単純ループにイテレータを使うコードは書きません。

```
  for (test& t : *v3)
    t.mPlay();
```

```
  for (test* t : v2)
    t->mPlay();
```

で済みます。環境によってはC++-11を有効化する必要があるかも知れません。

Answer (score 0):

太古の [c++98](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b98) に縛られずにもっと新しい文法を使えば単純明快

```
for (auto& a : v2) {
    a->mPlay();
}
```

iterator はポインタを更に抽象化したものなのでうんぬんの話は例えば
[イテレータとポインタの違い](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6882/)
[意味の分からないコード２つの意味が知りたい。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/49569/)

[c++98](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b98) 縛りがあるなら

`*itr` と書いたら `vector<test*>` の要素が得られる、すなわち `*itr` の型は `test*`
ポインタ経由でメンバ関数を呼ぶなら `->` が必要
演算子の結合順から `*itr->mPlay()` ではダメで `(*itr)->mPlay()` とする

ってだけのことです。